# SAML Configuration for Azure SSO with Angular Frontend and .NET Backend

Tags: .net, angular, azure, single-sign-on, saml

I am trying to configure SAML in .NET for Azure SSO and I followed this example:

https://matthijs.hoekstraonline.net/2020/04/14/authenticate-an-azure-ad-user-with-saml-for-asp-net-core/

However, I get the following error:

> "Access to XMLHttpRequest at "https://login.microsoftonline.com/../
> (redirected from "https://localhost:44.." from origin
> "http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource."

I have been told that I need not do anything in Angular and configuring in .NET will suffice. I have seen answers where others are using JWT authentication as well. I am unable to understand if this can be achieved without using JWT?

P.S. I am using REST API and not MVC.

Answer (score 0):

I had experienced a similar error (No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.) when I was first connecting my front end and back end. The solution in my case was to add cors configurations to the ?Backend web.config under <system.webServer> to allow access from the given domain. This also allows for credentials to be passed to the backend application from your front end Angular.

```
        <cors enabled="true">
            <add origin="<Front End Domain>" allowCredentials="true">
                <allowMethods>
                    <add method="GET" />
                    <add method="POST" />
                    <add method="PUT" />
                    <add method="OPTIONS" />
                </allowMethods>
                <allowHeaders>
                    <add header="content-type" />
                    <add header="accept" />
                </allowHeaders>
            </add>
        </cors>
```